# Auto-renewable monthly subscriptions - when is the expired day?

Tags: ios

Auto-renewable monthly subscriptions
User start subscription when

```
case-1. 12.15 -> 1.15 -> 2.15 -> 3.15 -> 4.15 

case-2. 12.31 -> 1.31 -> 2.28 -> 3.31 -> 4.30 -> 5.31

case-3. 12.30 -> 1.30 -> 2.28 -> 3.30 -> 4.30 -> 5.30
```

when is the renewing day about case2 and case3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The renewal process is described in detail in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html)

> The subscription renewal process begins in the ten days before the expiration date. During those ten days, the App Store checks for any billing issues that might delay or prevent the subscription from being automatically renewed
>
> During the 24-hour period before the subscription expires, the App Store starts trying to automatically renew it. The App Store makes several attempts to automatically renew the subscription over a period of time but eventually stops if there are too many failed attempts.

So, for the start dates in your question, the renewal dates would be:

1. Jan 14, Feb 14, March 14 and so on
2. Jan 30, Feb 27 (or 28 if it is a leap year), March 30, April 30
3. Jan 29, Feb 27 (or 28 if it is a leap year), March 29, April 29